# wkhtmltopdf: What paper sizes are valid?

Tags: php, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I am using [wkhtmltopdf(html to pdf converter)](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and am running it through a php `shell_exec`.

When running `wkhtmltopdf --help` one option is size, with the help text being

> Set paper size to: A4, Letter, etc.

I am wondering if someone has a list of paper sizes this executable will run?

The specific version is [wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2&can=2)

Comment: Related: [How to convert HTML into endless one-page PDF via wkhtmltopdf?](http://superuser.com/q/958988/87805) at SU

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you take a look through the [pdfsettings.cc source in the project repository](https://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/src/lib/pdfsettings.cc), you'll find this list, which looks to me like the accepted list of named paper sizes.

```
res["A0"] = QPrinter::A0;
res["A1"] = QPrinter::A1;
res["A2"] = QPrinter::A2;
res["A3"] = QPrinter::A3;
res["A4"] = QPrinter::A4;
res["A5"] = QPrinter::A5;
res["A6"] = QPrinter::A6;
res["A7"] = QPrinter::A7;
res["A8"] = QPrinter::A8;
res["A9"] = QPrinter::A9;
res["B0"] = QPrinter::B0;
res["B1"] = QPrinter::B1;
res["B10"] = QPrinter::B10;
res["B2"] = QPrinter::B2;
res["B3"] = QPrinter::B3;
res["B4"] = QPrinter::B4;
res["B5"] = QPrinter::B5;
res["B6"] = QPrinter::B6;
res["B7"] = QPrinter::B7;
res["B8"] = QPrinter::B8;
res["B9"] = QPrinter::B9;
res["C5E"] = QPrinter::C5E;
res["Comm10E"] = QPrinter::Comm10E;
res["DLE"] = QPrinter::DLE;
res["Executive"] = QPrinter::Executive;
res["Folio"] = QPrinter::Folio;
res["Ledger"] = QPrinter::Ledger;
res["Legal"] = QPrinter::Legal;
res["Letter"] = QPrinter::Letter;
res["Tabloid"] = QPrinter::Tabloid;
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be some unlimited height option.

Comment: @kenorb and also unlimited height paper and printer :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following, they worked for me:

1. Legal
2. Letter
3. Tabloid
4. A4
5. A3
6. B5
7. B4
8. B3

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of supported page sizes at https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#PaperSize-enum

```
A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,C5E,Comm10E,DLE,Executive,Folio,Ledger,Legal,Letter,Tabloid,Custom
```

Note "custom" at the end of the list. You can specify `--page-width size` and `--page-height size` with size being 1in, 3mm, 5cm, etc