# letter spacing issue when converting html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf through pdfkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

My HTML file has some paragraphs where I am using an 8pt font-size. After converting the HTML to PDF, the paragraphs gain extra letter spacing and some letters are overlapped.

I tried all the suggestions from the following (like using dpi and xserver) but none are working.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=72&q=letter

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this question is a little bit old. But having received my fair share of frustration from this wkhtmltopdf letter-spacing issue, I want to drop a potential workaround:

```
'--dpi 96'
```

Add this option to the binary parameters, and you might be able to smile as I eventually did!
viz:

```
wkhtmltopdf --option1 --option2 --dpi 96 "www.host.com/page.html" file.pdf
```

Comment: As the OP says: "After converting the HTML to PDF, the paragraphs gain extra letter spacing and some letters are overlapped." That was also my experience for any text where I had applied CSS `letter-spacing`, until I added the dpi option as above. Just a workaround! I honestly do not fully grasp the error - a bug, I guess.

Comment: Nice workaround - however extra space is still here. Ever found a perene solution ?

Comment: "Perene"? Guess you mean permanent as in "perennial"! Well, sadly nope. Actually, I haven't dwelt on this issue much lately.

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't realize it at first, because I've been having a separate issue where I'm not seeing certain styles show up. I ran the following tests: without dpi specified convert an html element that does not have letter-spacing style applied, and see that the letter-spacing is less in the pdf. Without dpi specified convert an element with letter-spacing: 1px; and see that letter spacing is more than 1px in the pdf (looks more like 5px). With dpi specified convert an element with letter-spacing 1px and notice that there is more spacing than with no letter-spacing specified.

Comment: This worked for me, too, on version 0.12.3 with a negative letter-spacing of -0.3mm.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me with dpi 96, and now the letter spacing is great!

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 I fixed this by using 200 dpi.

Answer (score 0):

Guys if you want to to get your PDF View as it looks in your Web Page copy the following code in your config/initializer/pdfkit.rb(create this file in initializer folder)

```
PDFKit.configure do |config| 
config.wkhtmltopdf ='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
config.default_options = {
   :encoding=>"UTF-8",
   :page_size=>"Ledger",
   :zoom => '1.3',
   :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
}
end
```

Plese check this link for more ":page_size "attributes

[wkhtmltopdf: What paper sizes are valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394905/wkhtmltopdf-what-paper-sizes-are-valid)

And discover new options by visiting this link

http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html

Hope This all will help you. Thanks

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be zoom 1.33 ?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update wkhtmltopdf.

I found the best way to fix these letter spacing issues is to just ensure you're using the latest version of `wkhtmltopdf` (0.12.2.1 at the time of writing).

In Rails you can simply use the edge binary gem of this, like so:

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'
```

Give that a quick try first and see if your issues are fixed. Mine were.