# pdfkit command failed: "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "Letter" ".... "--quiet" "-" "-"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

i'm using pdfkit for generating pdf when i generate pdf it gives me following error.

```
command failed: "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "Letter" 
"--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" 
"0.75in" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--print-media-type" 
"--quiet" "-" "-"
```

Any help?

- Ateq

Answer (score 6):

Hello Guys i serached it on google and find answer on a blog.Thanks guys.

```
Solution is here.
(1)# first, installing dependencies
 $sudo aptitude install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev

(2)# for 64bits OS Run one by one following commands.

$sudo wget http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
$sudo tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
$sudo mv wkhtmltopdf-amd64 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
$sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Finally Go to your rails app/config/initializer Folder and create new file pdfkit.rb and paste following code in it.

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
   config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf' if Rails.env.production?
end
```

Thats it.Now your pdf file will be download.
Also visit for further information 
http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/generating-pdfs-in-rails-with-pdfkit-and-deploying-to-a-server/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Also Guys if you want to to get your PDF View as it looks in your Web Page copy the following code in your config/initializer/pdfkit.rb(create this file in initializer folder)

```
PDFKit.configure do |config| 
config.wkhtmltopdf ='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
config.default_options = {
   :encoding=>"UTF-8",
   :page_size=>"Ledger",
   :zoom => '1.3',
   :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
}
end
```

Plese check this link for more ":page_size "attributes

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394905/wkhtmltopdf-what-paper-sizes-are-valid
```

And discover new options by visiting this link

```
http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html
```

Hope This all will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: I had a big problem with pdfkit in production and I lost few hours fixing and your section 'config.default.options' solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the right binary version of `bit` according to your operating system. I had experienced a wrong version problem when I use the 32 bit binary onto a 64bit ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade to wkhtmltopdf ( 0.12.2.1 woked for me)

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

ubuntu 14.04 users may get into dependancy problem when installing https://askubuntu.com/a/625225/106182

Answer (score 0):

In case of you are calling through rails controller, make sure that you set layout false.