# Does wkHTMLtoPDF support @page rules?

Tags: css, pdf, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I've been trying to use this simple command to explore wkHTML2PDF abilities:

```
wkhtml2pdf test.htm test.pdf
```

It seems it doesn't support @page rules that might be included in an attached CSS file, or do I miss something? some parameters for examples?

Comment: You have optional parameters for page size: `--page-size` ([check valid formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394905/wkhtmltopdf-what-paper-sizes-are-valid)), but there is also `--page-width`, `--page-height`. Take a look at [manual](https://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html).

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is No.  As @skobajic mentioned, there are command line parameters to get the same functionality.  I don't see it coming any time soon given that webkit doesn't support it.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2200

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15548